# How to analyze only .py files in SonarQube properties file?

Tags: python, sonarqube

I am using SonarQube for my work project. We have a repository with a lot of files and folders in our project. I want to filter out only the python files (.py files).

My goal is to analyze only the .py files in the folder `repo/src`.

I tried using the [wildcards](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/), but to no avail.

Here are the two things I tried :

```
sonar.sources=repo/src/**/*.py
sonar.sources=repo/src/**.py
```

The option of just passing the whole folder where the code is located (repo/src/) works, but the plan my work pays for SonarQube doesn't allow us to analyze the whole project, hence why I want to analyze only python files.

What am I doing wrong? Can someone let me know what I am misunderstanding here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying `sonar.exclusions` in addition to `sonar.sources`.

Before, there was [`sonar.language`](https://docs.sonarqube.org/7.4/analysis/analysis-parameters/), which you could set to `py` for Python:

> Set the language of the source code to analyze. Browse the Plugin Library page to get the list of all available languages. If not set, a multi-language analysis will be triggered

But that has *long* been deprecated and now does nothing in latest versions. From a thread on the Sonarqube forums, [What is the alternative to the sonar.language property in the current version of sonarqube?](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/what-is-the-alternative-to-the-sonar-language-property-in-the-current-version-of-sonarqube/3993):

> The alternative is to just not use it.
>
> ...
>
> Now if, on the other hand, you want to prevent other languages in the project from being analyzed, then you should do one of these things:
>
> - configure `sonar.sources` not to include those files, assuming this can be done conveniently
> - [set exclusions](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/)
> - as a last-ditch hack, there’s also the option of configuring language file suffixes at the project level to not recognize the other languages’ files (e.g. set the Java file suffix to `.foo`)

A reply on that same thread said that this worked for them:

> so in my case the exclusions property looks like this
>
> ```
> sonar.exclusions=**/*.java,**/*.jar
> ```

So, first, change [`sonar.sources`](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/analysis-parameters/) to specify **directories**.

> Comma-separated paths to directories containing main source files.

```
sonar.sources=repo/src
```

Then specify `sonar.exclusions` for the file extensions to ignore.

We have the same setup in our projects:

```
sonar.sources=app
sonar.exclusions=**/*.html,**/*.js
```

You can check from the sonar scanner logs if some files were excluded:

```
INFO: Indexing files...
INFO: Project configuration:
INFO:   Excluded sources: **/*.html,**/*.js
INFO:   Excluded sources for coverage: tests/*
INFO: 266 files indexed
INFO: 24 files ignored because of inclusion/exclusion patterns
INFO: 1 file ignored because of scm ignore settings
...
```

(We are using SonarQube server 9.5.0.56709, SonarScanner 4.3.0.2102)